# sqlite correct path/URI for php pdo on windows

Tags: php, windows, sqlite, path, pdo

[ante-scriptum : this is a self answered question, you don't need to bother answering]

I ran into a weird configuration problem, not documented anywhere on the [specific PHP.net page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php) or at StackOverflow.

### The problem

When opening an existing sqlite database on Windows, the same error kept showing :

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] Unable To Open Database File`

Although the code executed was copy/pasted from the manual :

```
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'sqlite:/full/path/to/db';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

I could not open this database, as I had tried all kinds of various DSN while googling :

`$dsn = 'sqlite:/c:\\full\\path\\to\\db'; // --FAILED--`

`$dsn = 'sqlite://c:/full/path/to/db'; // --FAILED--`

Comment: Nice work. As soon as I can vote again this gets a +1 from me since you posted your own answer!

Comment: @MatNadrofsky Thanks for that, and thanks for your editing, I appreciate correct english too !

Comment: @MatNadrofsky solution posted, got me finally 2 more days

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### The solution

Notice the simple slash in the DSN `sqlite:/` ? Just drop it !

write your DSN like this :

`sqlite:name.db`.

This works with **relative** and **absolute** paths so :

`$dsn = 'sqlite:c:\full\path\to\name.db'; // --WORKS--`

`$dsn = 'sqlite:..\data\name.db'; // --WORKS--`

`$dsn = 'sqlite:name.db'; // --WORKS--`

Hope it will save you some time in the future !

Comment: I don't know when it stopped, but it doesn't seem to work with relative paths any more ([see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php)).

Comment: @dhobbs, did you test it in practice? Relative paths work with PHP 5.4, despite the documentation was [the same at the time](https://web.archive.org/web/20160115102733/http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php).

Comment: @user, I did encounter the inability to use a relative path at that time, which is why I ended up commenting here, but I no longer have that project and don't remember all the details.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small append to [@justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093649/justin-t) answer:

You can also use the linux path style on windows:

```
$dsn = 'sqlite:c:/full/path/to/name.db';
```

Answer (score 0):

Better than `PDO('sqlite:...')` is to use PHP `sqlite3` extension and its `SQLite3` class. I have tried your advices above with a database on an external (hard)drive and it didn't work (still giving the same error as mentioned in the first post by @justin-t). Then I tried with `SQLite3` class and... Hurray! It worked!

(Just for those who are wondering about PDO and a lot of its weird bugs.)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your PHP installation has enabled extensions for sqlite and/or sqlite3.

I've been struggling with a similar problem only to find that it rejected my DSN because sqlite was disabled.