# Setting sqlite3 database path using PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Having a hard time to figure out the path to set for my sqlite3 database using PDO in PHP.

My code as follows:

```
$handle = new PDO('sqlite:/C:/New folder/sqlite/test.db') or die("Could not open 
database");
echo $handle;
$query = "SELECT * FROM student";
```

Debugging result:

It returns a blank web page instead of printing out the $handle. I already set my desired path where my sqlite database file was stored. What did i miss out ?

Kindly advise.

Comment: blank web page often means fatal error. Turn up error reporting and turn on display errors. google how if needed.

Comment: already tried using try catch exception to see what's the error. but still nothing comes out.

Comment: thats because php rarely throws exceptions when an error occurs. its not the way to debug.

Comment: i think my error came out was 'could not find driverError in query: not an error'. Not sure what driver is required. I already have all the extensions.

Comment: That's weird, SQLite driver is installed and enabled by default. Are you using a shared web host? It's possible that the provider has manually disabled SQLite in PDO. Also, are you sure that the "nothing" you're printing isn't something that can't be printed? Try var_export($handle) instead of echo $handle.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670687/sqlite-correct-path-uri-for-php-pdo-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to know what PDO drivers are installed, make a blank file with in it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then look for the PDO section and you should see somthing along the lines of:

`PDO drivers    mysql, sqlite, sqlite2`

If you only have `mysql` then you need to install the sqlite pdo driver. Use google for that, dont forget also check your production server too, else your create something you possibly cant use on your hosting.

As the PDO driver is much like the old `sqlite_open()` it will create the database file for you if its not found.

also as you may be aware spaces in file paths are not so good and can cause problems,

Instead of using: 
`sqlite:/C:/New folder/sqlite/test.db` you should at least rename your New Folder to somthing else: `sqlite:/New_folder/sqlite/test.db`

Comment: Something wrong with my files that's why i'm not able to open. Anyway thanks!